# spring boot java app - receiving image/png from golang with different byte size, how to extract raw png from inputstream?

Tags: spring-boot, go

I am fetching a png image from golang server to spring boot java application. There is a difference in the size sent and sent of bytes received in spring boot app and due to that, it is not getting processed as a valid png image. The `Content-Type` received is `image/png; charset=utf-8`.

Is `charset=utf-8` normally set even for binary output? Is that the reason for difference in bytes? How to extract raw png image from the response inputstream? Appreciate your help.

go code

```go
w http.ResponseWriter
...
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileNameOfDownload + "\"")
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(result)))

fmt.Println("Length of result: being set:", len(result), strconv.Itoa(len(result)), w.Header().Get("Content-Length"))
//Length of result: being set: 60753 60753 60753

w.Header().Set("Allow", "GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token , Authorization")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Write(result)
```

spring boot snippet

```java
System.out.println("ResponseDetails:" + httpsCon.getResponseCode() + ":" +
                    httpsCon.getContentType() + ":" + httpsCon.getContentLength() + ":" +
                    httpsCon.getHeaderField("Content-Length"))
//ResponseDetails:200:image/png; charset=utf-8:110286:110286
```